# My code does not insert data into the database

Tags: mysql, sql, lua

```
function registerAccount(login, password, email, reference)
    local checkUsername = exports.TR_mysql:query("SELECT UID FROM `dhiran` WHERE `login` = ? LIMIT 1", login)
    if checkUsername and checkUsername[1] then
        triggerClientEvent(client, "loginResponseServer", resourceRoot, "Já existe um usuário com esse tipo de login.", "error")
        return
    end

    local serial = getPlayerSerial(client)
    local checkSerial = exports.TR_mysql:query("SELECT UID FROM `dhiran` WHERE `serial` = ? LIMIT 1", serial)
    if checkSerial and #checkSerial == 2 then
        triggerClientEvent(client, "loginResponseServer", resourceRoot, "Você já esgotou o limite de criação de contas em uma série(2).", "error")
        return
    end

    local checkEmail = exports.TR_mysql:query("SELECT UID FROM `dhiran` WHERE `email` = ? LIMIT 1", email)
    if checkEmail and checkEmail[1] then
        triggerClientEvent(client, "loginResponseServer", resourceRoot, "Este e-mail já está atribuído a uma conta.", "error")
        return
    end


    local referenceUID = false
    if reference then
        referenceUID = teaDecodeBinary(reference, "XayDpN36bGKGvfbD")
        if tonumber(referenceUID) == nil or string.len(referenceUID) < 1 then
            triggerClientEvent(client, "loginResponseServer", resourceRoot, "O código de referência é inválido.", "error", "reference")
            return
        end
    end

    exports.TR_mysql:query("INSERT INTO dhiran (login, password, email, serial, createIP, position, referencedPlayer, money, phoneBlocked) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '[[]]')", login, passwordHash(password, "bcrypt", {}), email, getPlayerSerial(client), getPlayerIP(client), settings.spawnPositions[math.random(1, #settings.spawnPositions)], referenceUID and referenceUID or false, referenceUID and 500 or 0)
    triggerClientEvent(client, "loginResponseServer", resourceRoot, false, "success", "accountCreate")
end
addEvent("registerAccount", true)
addEventHandler("registerAccount", resourceRoot, registerAccount)
```

My code does not insert data into the database, it says that the same login already exists, but there isn't.. i've been trying to solve it for a few hours, but I can't

Please help me <3